# Why is -ldl needed for linking .so files but not needed for .dylib files?

Tags: linker, g++, shared-libraries, glfw, dylib

I was linking the glfw3 library for my opengl project. I tried compiling and running my codes in both the Mac and Linux environment. In Linux, the glfw3 library was stored as `libglfw.so.3.2`, whereas in Mac, it was stored as `libglfw.3.2.dylib`.

For linking this library for g++, in Mac, I just needed to use the following codes

```
g++ -o Animation glad.o Animation.o -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw
```

Where as in Linux, I had to include `-ldl`, or else it would print an error.

```
g++ -o Animation glad.o Animation.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ldl -lglfw
```

Why is `-ldl` a necessity for `.so` files but not for `.dylib` files? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different systems split functions across different libraries.  POSIX requires that applications link against certain libraries when they use functions from some header files:

- [c99 - compile standard C programs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html#tag_20_11_13)

Note that for most libraries, POSIX says that the *implementation may search this library in the absence of this option*.  Most implementations use this permission to put at least some functions into the main C library, so it can be used without linking explicitly to the POSIX-mandated library.  The result is that on some systems you need to link against these libraries, but not on others.

Technically, the Linux (glibc?) solution is not POSIX-compliant because `-ldl` is not listed as a library required to use functions from `<dlfcn.h>`.  Some libraries are missing as well (such as `-lxnet`).  `autoconf` was born in part due to this variance among historic UNIX implementations:

- [Library Files](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Libraries.html#Libraries)